# Unable to paste anything in the mounted folder for S3

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-s3, ubuntu-14.04, mount, s3fs

I mounted my `S3` bucket on `Ubuntu 14.0`, by following instructions in [S3FS-Fuse](https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse). I can see the content of the bucket in the folder. But when I try to paste something in the folder, I'm getting permission denied error:

[image]

This error is when trying to upload from Node `Multer`. Even trying locally Copy/Paste fails with same error. Tried `chmod 777 mys3mt/` and get Input/output error :

[image]

On the bucket in AWS console, I've given Read and Write Permission for Everybody for both, Object Access and Permissions Access. Anything uploaded to the S3 bucket is listed in Ubuntu. But I am not able to add anything from Ubuntu.

What am I missing? Please help.

Many thanks.

Comment: You cannot change permission using a wrapper filesystem, nor you should play the s3 to s3 copy , the author didn't even mentioned used of s3transfer. Stick to AWS CLI or SDK as suggested by @JohnRotenstein .

Comment: Thn how can I transfer files to S3 from Nodejs ? I also want to be able to convert a file using `ffmpeg` and upload to `S3`.

Comment: To communicate with Amazon S3 from node.js, use the [AWS JavaScript SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/documentation/sdk-for-javascript/).

Comment: I want to convert an uploaded gif file to mp4 and upload that to S3. I cannot do that unless I mount S3 locally (atleast i think so) .. How can I do it?